# Get/Post запросы

Tags: python, json, post, get

У меня имеется сайт на котором есть конкретное поле, после ввода значения в это поле содержимое страницы меняется, то есть просто при вводе, не надо нажимать отправить или что то подтверждать, могу ли я как то с помощью запросов вводить значения в это поле и получать меняющиеся переменные этой страницы? Пытался после ввода значений найти в запросах что нибудь, но там ничего нет, т. к. я не отправлял никаких данных//

Пример:[image: пример]

С помощью запроса передать данные в красное поле и после получить данные из зеленого поля

Если с помощью запросов подобное нереализуемо, то подскажите пожалуйста через что такое можно сделать (Селениум не предлагать)

Comment: Почему вам не подходит Selenium?

Comment: в каждом цикле надо будет получать актуальные данные, слишком долго будет идти цикл если делать это через селениум, либо мне нужно чтобы селениум для каждого цикла обновлял данные не закрываясь, так я не умею) думал через гет запросы будет полегче сделать

Comment: Сделайте один `driver.get()` и не вызывайте `driver.quit()`. Селениум сам по себе работает очень быстро. Можете настроить в `WebDriverWait` polling_frequency 100 мс, и вы заметить не успеете, как Selenium будет реагировать на изменения на странице.